# Assertion failed for intel_gpu_top

Tags: time, terminal, gpu, intel

I installed intel-gpu-tools using

`sudo apt-get install intel-gpu-tools`

While using intel_gpu_time it works. For intel_gpu_top, it is not working. It is showing the assertion failed error as

```
intel_gpu_top: ../../lib/instdone.c:329: init_instdone_definitions: Assertion `(devid == 0x3577 || devid == 0x2562 || devid == 0x3582 || devid == 0x2572)' failed.
```

Referring to the link

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/798114/how-to-know-the-utilization-of-intel-gpu-in-ubuntu

Is there anyway to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to show your Ubuntu version and intel-gpu-tools version. Apparently your GPU is not in the asserted four types.

You could check the device IDs for module types with these links.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Second_generation

https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools/tree/lib/intel_chipset.h

To use intel-gpu-tools, you could try to download and compile their latest code from the development site.

https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools/